# Using roll=TRUE with allow.cartesian=TRUE

Tags: r, join, data.table, cartesian-product

What is the best way to do a Cartesian join and use the roll forward feature, but applying the roll feature to each alternative series from the joining table, rather than the whole series.

Best explained with an example:

```
library(data.table)
A = data.table(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = letters[1:5])
B = data.table(x = c(1,2,3,1,4), f = c("Alice","Alice","Alice", "Bob","Bob"), z = 101:105)
setkey(B,x)
C = B[A, roll = TRUE, allow.cartesian=TRUE, rollends = FALSE]

A
B
C[f == "Alice"]
C[f == "Bob"]
C
```

So we have the two starting tables:

```
> A
   x y
1: 1 a
2: 2 b
3: 3 c
4: 4 d
5: 5 e
> B
   x     f   z
1: 1 Alice 101
2: 1   Bob 104
3: 2 Alice 102
4: 3 Alice 103
5: 4   Bob 105
```

And I want to join these so that I have **for each** `x` value in `A` I have both and `Alice` and `Bob` row, rolling forwards if either are missing (but not rolling past the end).  This doesn't quite work as I've currently got it:

```
> C[f == "Alice"]
   x     f   z y
1: 1 Alice 101 a
2: 2 Alice 102 b
3: 3 Alice 103 c
> C[f == "Bob"]
   x   f   z y
1: 1 Bob 104 a
2: 4 Bob 105 d
> C
   x     f   z y
1: 1 Alice 101 a
2: 1   Bob 104 a
3: 2 Alice 102 b
4: 3 Alice 103 c
5: 4   Bob 105 d
6: 5    NA  NA e
```

Because Alice is there for 2 and 3, it doesn't roll Bob's data forwards.  I need the extra rows for Bob so I want to get:

```
> C[f == "Alice"]
   x     f   z y
1: 1 Alice 101 a
2: 2 Alice 102 b
3: 3 Alice 103 c
> C[f == "Bob"]
   x   f   z y
1: 1 Bob 104 a
2: 2 Bob 104 b  # THESE ROWS ARE MISSING
3: 3 Bob 104 c  # THESE ROWS ARE MISSING
4: 4 Bob 105 d
> C
   x     f   z y
1: 1 Alice 101 a
2: 1   Bob 104 a
3: 2 Alice 102 b
4: 2   Bob 104 b  # THESE ROWS ARE MISSING
5: 3 Alice 103 c
6: 3   Bob 104 c  # THESE ROWS ARE MISSING
7: 4   Bob 105 d
8: 5    NA  NA e
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
setkey(B, f, x)

setkey(B[CJ(unique(f), unique(x)), allow.cartesian = T,
         roll = T, rollends = c(F,F)], x)[A, allow.cartesian = T]
#   x     f   z y
#1: 1 Alice 101 a
#2: 1   Bob 104 a
#3: 2 Alice 102 b
#4: 2   Bob 104 b
#5: 3 Alice 103 c
#6: 3   Bob 104 c
#7: 4 Alice  NA d
#8: 4   Bob 105 d
#9: 5    NA  NA e
```

And you can filter out the `NA`'s to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks @eddi, I'm accepting this answer, because it is fastest and accurately answer the question, but I've also posted an alternative below that I've stumbled across, since it seemed sufficient different and may be useful to someone.

Comment: Reading this makes me think that it would be nice to have some way to set key within [] to keep the natural left right data flow

Comment: @ClaytonStanley such an option (a `key` argument to `[.data.table`) was briefly available (in 1.8.11 I think), but it was rolled back as it didn't seem like it was used much and it was a bit confusing

Comment: @eddi I know this is outside the discussion of the post, but what about getting something like: `tbl[..][, setkey(.SD, x)][..]` to work; just a thought.

Comment: @ClaytonStanley that's a cool idea - it actually works right now and is interesting syntax :) The above can be re-written as `B[, setkey(.SD, f, x)][CJ(unique(f), unique(x)), allow.cartesian = T,roll = T, rollends = c(F,F)][, setkey(.SD, x)][A, allow.cartesian = T]` which works as expected. The more I stare at it the more I like it!

Comment: Well how about that. Tested and works for me too. The only thing I noticed is that they setkey on the .SD doesn't persist outside of the pipeline. So, for example, after returning from that statement, B does not have a key (or has whatever key that it had before executing that line). Even if you just do `B[, setkey(.SD, f, x)]`, no key on B afterwards. I can't yet wrap my head around why that is the case. An implicit copy somewhere?

Comment: @ClaytonStanley it's same deal as when doing `dt[, list(a, b, c)]` or `dt[, .SD]` - this is a new `data.table` and not "part" of original `dt`

Answer (score 3):

I also found an alternative way of doing this. I've accepted the other answer as that produces a result more closely matching that requested by the question, but this might also be useful for some people.  The difference is what happens at the end of the series.

```
C = B[, .SD[A, roll = TRUE, rollends = FALSE], by = f]
setkey(C, x)

> C
        f x   z y
 1: Alice 1 101 a
 2:   Bob 1 104 a
 3: Alice 2 102 b
 4:   Bob 2 104 b
 5: Alice 3 103 c
 6:   Bob 3 104 c
 7: Alice 4  NA d
 8:   Bob 4 105 d
 9: Alice 5  NA e
10:   Bob 5  NA e
```

Row 9 & 10 are the only difference; in eddi's answer these are combined as a single row, with `NA` in both columns.

This solution is also slightly slower than eddi's when I tested on bigger data.tables (although both are quite fast).